# Tool to generate SQL query with multiple record sets from xml source containing database relationships

Tags: xml, sql-server, orm

I have xml files that describe data I want to retrieve out of an MS SQL database.
e.g.

```
<Customer Type="Entity" ID="12345">
  <Territory Type="Entity" Table="Territory" Join="Territory.TerritoryID = Customer.TerritoryID"></Territory>  
  <Addresses Type="Collection" Table="Address" Join="Address.AddressID = Customer.AddressID"></Addresses>
  <Orders Type="Collection" Table="Order" Join="Order.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID">
    <BillToAdress Type="Entity" Table="Address" Join="Address.AddressID = Order.BillToAddressID"></BillToAdress>
    <ShipToAddress Type="Entity" Table="Address" Join="Address.AddressID = Order.ShipToAddressID"></ShipToAddress>
    <OrderLines Type="Collection" Table="OrderLine" Join="OrderLine.OrderID = Order.OrderID">
      <Product Type="Entity" Table="Product" Join="Product.ProductID = OrderLine.ProductID">
        <ProductParts Type="Collection" Table="ProductPart" Join="ProductPart.ProductID = Product.ProductID"></ProductParts>
      </Product>
    </OrderLines>
  </Orders>
</Customer>
```

Importantly, the only ID contained in the xml is in the root node (CustomerID). All other data would be retrieved from joins to related tables, the relationships of which are defined in the xml.

I am looking for a tool that takes in xml in similar format and can output a single SQL script to retrieve all data below in one hit.

All the ORM tools I know of issue queries sequentially, so e.g. results from the Customer table need to be returned to the application before the Territory query is run (using the TerritoryID returned from the Customer query).

Does anyone know of such a tool/library? Thanks

Customer

| CustomerID | Name | TerritoryID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Acme Ltd | 67 |

Territory

| TerritoryID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 67 | California |

Address

| AddressID | CustomerID | Address1 | Address2 | City | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 890123 | 12345 | 12 Some Street |  | Beverly Hills | 90210 |
| 890124 | 12345 | 23 Some Road |  | Inglewood | 90310 |
| 890125 | 12345 | 34a Another Place |  | Santa Monica | 90410 |

Order

| OrderID | BillToAddressID | ShipToAddressID | ProductID | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6789012 | 890123 | 890124 | 9876 | 50 | 200 |
| 6780123 | 890123 | 890125 | 7654 | 8 | 990 |

OrderLine

| OrderLineID | OrderID | ProductID | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 98765432 | 6789012 | 9876 | 50 | 90 |
| 98765433 | 6789012 | 9890 | 20 | 120 |
| 98789012 | 6780123 | 9890 | 8 | 990 |

Product

| ProductID | Description | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9876 | Widget Sml | Each |
| 9890 | Widget Lge | Each |

ProductPart

| ProductPartID | ProductID | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 9890 | Gadget A |
| 1234568 | 9890 | Fidget B |

Answer (score -1):

The closest thing I can think of is this [sqlizer.io](https://sqlizer.io/).